# resize container to image-size

Tags: html, css

I have a `container` and would like to resize the `height` of this container according to the size of the `image` inside.

HTML:

```
<figure class="container">
   <a class = "123">
      <img class="item" src="...">
   </a>
</figure>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 -10px 10px
}

.item {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px
}
```

Does anybody have an idea how I should go about this?

Comment: why u choose figure instead of a div layer?

Comment: @UnskilledFreak Figure might be more semantic.

Comment: I actually don't remember, did this a while ago. is it relevant to what I want to achieve?

Comment: @sehetmich no, it's not. You don't choose tags based on their CSS properties. You do so based on their semantic relevance.

Comment: since css doesn't have a parent selector, I'm pretty sure you'' have to use a script to do this.

Comment: @Mohamad: Ok, thanks! Can you think of a way to solve this? It must be an easy matter I suppose

Comment: Check the image height with $(".item").height(); And just give this to your .container element.

Comment: has it to be an container with image in link? why dont use an link only with `display:inline-block;` and the image as background? in them u only have to set width and height to that link

Answer (score 2):

The following might do the trick, use `display: inline-block` for the `figure` container and get rid of the extra white space after the image with `display: block`.

The inline-block will give you a shrink-to-fit height and width around the image (and link in your case).

```css
.container {
  border: 1px dotted blue; /* for demo only */
  display: inline-block;
}
.container img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<figure class="container">
   <a class = "123">
      <img class="item" src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
   </a>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<figure class="container">
   <a class = "123">
      <img class="item" src="...">
   </a>
</figure>

.container {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 -10px 10px
   height: auto;
   overflow: auto;
}

.item {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px
}
```

The container will wrap itself around the image and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

before you call the container you call which image you are going to use within the container, get the width and height of the image , now you know what you are going to use it so you can do inline styleing.

```
<?php
$img = "your image url comes here";
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img);
echo"
<figure class='container' style='width:$width;height:$height'>
   <a class = '123'>
      <img class='item' src='$img'>
   </a>
</figure>
";
?>
```